# How to apply a custum label on polygons in Geotools?

Tags: java, geotools

I am new to `Geotools` and I am stuck in trying to get custom labels on polygons in `Geotools`. What I get running is a map with the wanted regions filled with the liked colors.

Yet, it is needed to have different labelling than the standard postal code. I cannot find a way getting some free text as `label text`. An option would also be removing the standard label (not showing it) and create i.e. a point placed on the polygon having something like a free text label. This as well I get working, unfortunately.

Could anyone give me a hint how it is possible placing custom labels on `polygons`? Any help is very much appreciated!

Best regards
Jochen